# ZIP repertory: shutil.rmtree()

Tags: python, zip

I try to delet a ZIP repertory with all files into this ZIP repertory.

So i use the shutil.rmtree() function to do that:

```
shutil.rmtree('path/to/my/directory.zip')
```

I have that error:

```
NotADirectoryError: [WinError 267] Nom de répertoire non valide: 'directory.zip'
```

Someone know how to remove a directory which is a ZIP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve this issue with:

```
os.unlink('path/to/my/directory.zip')
```

and it's delet my all repertory '.zip'. It's work well for me.